# Error handling concept in batch

Tags: batch-file

i have written small below code in batch.from below the if not error level step not working properly. both conditions are executing. I tried with many ways but no luck. please help me fix this.It's error handling concept in deleting files more than 90 days concept.

codes are:

```
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b /s *_delete*') do (
    cd %%f
    if not exist "%%f" -s -m *.* -d -90 -c (
        Echo No folder or files in specified in condition
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            forfiles -p "%%f" -s -m *.* -d -90 -c "cmd /c echo del @path" 
        )
     )
)
```

the echo used in near del for debugging purpose.

Comment: Why does it look like you are trying to use options from the FORFILES command with your IF EXIST?

Comment: actually the forfiles that line will delete the more than 90 days files under _delete folder. sometime under that _delete folder no files will not available more than 90 days, so if not exist i need to display the echo "no folder or files that line, if exist i need to perform the delete action.

Comment: `-s -m *.* -d -90 -c` are parameters for `forfiles` and don't work outside the `forfiles`command.

Comment: You cannot use options from some other command with another command. The FORFILES options you are using with your IF NOT EXIST is invalid.

Comment: Can you advise me , how to proceed further ? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd c:\windows
forfiles /m win.ini
echo %errorlevel%
forfiles /m cat.txt
echo %errorlevel%
```

To actually use

```
forfiles /m win.ini
if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo files found
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo files not found
```

Comment: i want to check more than 90 days files only in that condition,if not the files not found option need to display...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Be specific.

Comment: i want to check more than 90 days files in particular directory ,if the directory does not has the files more than 90 days i want to print no folder or files in specified condition.(this is my requirement).if the directory has the files i need to delete the files.